# Remove calendar icon from Material-UI Date/TimePicker - but need to keep default validations

Tags: material-ui, datetimepicker

[image]

[image]

I need to hide or remove the calendar icon here **but need to keep validation as it is** - material ui **Date/Time Picker**

```
  <KeyboardDatePicker
        style={{ margin: 0, marginRight: '12px' }}
        minDate={defaultValues.id ? undefined : Date.now()}
        disableToolbar
        inputVariant='outlined'
        variant='inline'
        margin='normal'
        fullWidth
        format='yyyy/MM/dd'
        value={watch('date')}
        onChange={value => setValue('date', value)}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@mui/x-date-pickers` library correct way to hide a calendar icon is by updating InputAndormentProps of your date picker like this:

```
InputAdornmentProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding

> `KeyboardButtonProps={{ disabled: true, style: { display: 'none' } }}`

[image]

[image]

Cheers !!!